# Issue when running Gulp after Assemble update

Tags: javascript, gulp, assemble

I just did an update of the Assemble package in project and an error came up after running `$ gulp` in the terminal

[image]

here is the Gulp task

```
//Assemble load task
gulp.task('load', function(cb) {

  //Set main assemble options
  //app.option('layout', ['default']);
  app.layouts('app/layouts/*.hbs');
  app.pages('app/pages/**/*.hbs');
  app.partials('app/components/**/*.hbs');
  app.engine('hbs', require('engine-handlebars'));
  app.data(['app/{pages,components,data}/**/*.json']);

  // //Custom helpers
  app.helper('get', function(prop) {
    return get(this.context, prop);
  });

  app.helper('debug', function(data, options){
    console.log(data);
  });

  app.helper('pagename', function(){
    let url = get(this.context, 'view.path');;
    let pagenameArr = url.split('/');
    let pagename = _.last(pagenameArr);
        pagename = pagename.split('.')[0];
    return pagename;
  });


  cb();
});
```

and here is a link to the update they did

https://github.com/assemble/assemble/commit/48e0f941366ccfe0a28f7957b8a43af68125310b

any recommendation ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a broken dependency and has been fix. It also had nothing to do with the commit you linked to. It's just a coincidence that you pulled down the latest dependencies right after that commit.